# Unable to correctly set up AES decryption in VB .net

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to set up AES encryption/decryption across two different platforms. I've been having trouble getting VB.net to give me the expected output when I encrypt or decrypt so I did a little experiment:

Using the same System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged object to encrypt and decrypt I get the original data back but using different objects for the encryption and decryption I get different answers. My code is as follows

```
    Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged
    Dim AES2 As New System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged
    Dim key() As Byte = New Byte() {&HDE, &HAD, &HBE, &HEF, &HA5, &HF4, &H56, &H12, &HDE, &HAD, &HBA, &HAB, &H1, &H92, &H83, &H74}
    Dim nulliv() As Byte = New Byte() {&H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0}

    AES.Key = key
    AES.KeySize = 128
    AES.BlockSize = 128
    AES.Padding = Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.None
    AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC
    AES.IV = nulliv

    AES2.Key = key
    AES2.KeySize = 128
    AES2.BlockSize = 128
    AES2.Padding = Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.None
    AES2.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC
    AES2.IV = nulliv

    Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor()

    Dim input() As Byte = New Byte() {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H9A, &HBC, &HDE, &HF0, &H24, &H68, &HAC, &HE0, &H78, &H94, &H56, &H12}

    Dim enc() As Byte = DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length)

    Dim DESDecrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor
    Dim out() As Byte = DESDecrypter.TransformFinalBlock(enc, 0, enc.Length)

    Dim DESDecrypter2 As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES2.CreateDecryptor
    Dim out2() As Byte = DESDecrypter2.TransformFinalBlock(enc, 0, enc.Length)
```

I would expect input, out and out2 to match but they don't. input and out are the same but out2 is different. I can only assume that there is something stored in the AES object that I'm not setting up correctly or transferring between the objects correctly.

I originally tried ECB mode to simplify matters but wondered whether not setting up the IV was having an effect. So, I tried using CBC with the IV as zeros meaning it should be the same as ECB. In both cases I get the same problem of out and out2 not matching.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assign the `KeySize` property to 128. When you do, it causes `AesManaged` to null out the key you supplied earlier. `AesManaged` can derive the key size from the actual key you supply, so change it to this:

```
Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged
Dim AES2 As New System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged
Dim key() As Byte = New Byte() {&HDE, &HAD, &HBE, &HEF, &HA5, &HF4, &H56, &H12, &HDE, &HAD, &HBA, &HAB, &H1, &H92, &H83, &H74}
Dim nulliv() As Byte = New Byte() {&H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0}

AES.Key = key
AES.Padding = Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.None
AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC
AES.IV = nulliv

AES2.Key = key
AES2.Padding = Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.None
AES2.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC
AES2.IV = nulliv
'Rest of the code is the same.
```

Comment: PSA: Please reconsider using a null initialization vector, as that leads to security issues. IVs should be random, and they should never be reused. Also, now that your key is on StackOverflow, I would recommend not using that key you posted. Finally, setting padding mode to `None` is also discouraged. Use PKCS#7 instead.

Comment: That's it! Thanks very much. That had been driving me potty. As for using a proper IV and another key yes I am totally with you, this code was just so that I could start getting consistent answers. I'll now be taking what I've learned and writing it up properly. I'm not sure what I'll do about padding yet, the other part of this is an embedded platform that I'm trying to send as little data from as possible. Anyway the important thing is that I can now get the same answer on both platforms. Thanks again.